# A bug causes crash when class inherit from cv2.KeyPoint

Tags: python, opencv

Look this code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
class T(cv2.KeyPoint):
    def __init__(self, pt):
        super().__init__()
        self.pt = pt
def calculate_corners(A):
    A_gray = cv2.cvtColor(A, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    pa = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(A_gray, maxCorners=100, qualityLevel=0.01, minDistance=15)
    pa = np.squeeze(pa)
    kpa = []
    for coor in pa:
        kpa.append(T(tuple(coor)))
    return kpa

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("E:\\video\\test.mp4")
while True:
    frame = cap.read()[1]
    if frame is None:
        break
    kpa = calculate_corners(frame)
    frame_corner = cv2.drawKeypoints(frame, kpa, outImage=None, color=(255, 0, 125))
    cv2.imshow('frame_corner', frame_corner)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

This code will crash in my system(Windows10, python3.7.3, opencv4.1.0)

After test, I'm sure this is caused by class T. I guess that class T dose not inherit release moudle of cv2.KeyPoint, so it cause memory leak. It's just my conjecture, and I didn't know how to fix it. Could anyone give me some advice? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @furas I would like to post the error message if I got it. But the program crash without any error message. You can try to run my code(please remember replace the video path).

Answer (score 0):

I seem to carry coals to Newcastle. I don't need create a class T, just use
 the cv2.KeyPoint.

Replace `T(tuple(coor))` with `cv2.KeyPoint(x=coor[0], y=coor[1], _size=0)`.

But I still want to know what cause program crash.